# Adding new instance of row, unable to update cell raw values

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I've stumped myself on what I thought was a pretty simple JavaScript function. The function takes 2 parameters. The first is a listbox (`oField`), and the second is a table (`nTable`).

The listbox is populated by the user, and each time this listbox's values are changed, I want the function below to be called, to recreate `nTable`, the original header, and rows for each value in the list box.

```
function table_build(oField, nTable){
    //clear table when selection changes
    nTable._HeaderRow.setInstances(1);
    //add new selection to table
    for(i=0;i<oField.length;i++){
        nTable._HeaderRow.addInstance(true);
        nTable.HeaderRow[i+1].Cell1.rawValue = oField.getDisplayItem(i);    
    }   
}
```

The issue that I am having is with the following line:

```
nTable.HeaderRow[i+1].Cell1.rawValue = oField.getDisplayItem(i);
```

I am able to update the value of the header row using:

```
nTable.HeaderRow.Cell1.rawValue = oField.getDisplayItem(i);
```

Which is weird, because I would have expected it to require `HeaderRow[0]` after the new instance is added.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a solution. The `addInstance()` function returns the new row instance. So I have updated my `table_build()` function to assign that value to a variable(`nRow`), then use `nRow` to reference the row.

```
var nRow = nTable._HeaderRow.addInstance(true);
nRow.Cell1.rawValue = oField.getDisplayItem(i);
```

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar query :)